# How can I call a standard .NET assembly within SQL

Tags: .net, sql, xml, encode, decode

I am having an issue whereby a column within a table of mine has data which is encoded using the System.Xml.XmlConvert.Encode method.

Now I need to manipulate this data within SQL and have not found a way to duplicate the System.Xml.XmlConvert.Decode method.

So I've been investigating how I can use the System.XML namespace within SQL to access this method WITHOUT having to wrap it inside one of my own assemblies. Is this possible? i.e. how can I access this assembly directly via T-SQL?

Comment: I would be surprised if this was possible.

Comment: Yes, it is possible if your version of SQL Server supports the integrated CLR environment.

Comment: If possible, how would I do this. I don't want to write a .NET wrapper and use the Create Assembly bit. I want to access the System.XML namespace directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There quite a few examples of writing add-ins using .NET for SQL. I believe you will need to have SQL 2005 or newer to create an add-in.

Here is an example that is particularly useful.

[Creating CLR SQL User Defined Function to Validate Values Using Regular Expressions @ MSDN](http://weblogs.asp.net/farhank/archive/2008/07/04/creating-clr-sql-user-defined-function-to-validate-values-using-regular-expression.aspx)

In your case, you will probably want to write a function that takes a byte[] and returns a string (decode), along with a corresponding function that takes a string and returns a byte[].

Actually I'm not sure that you can directly use byte[], but you should be able to write a corresponding wrapper function in SQL that can take a hex string and turn it into a varbinary() if that is necessary.

**edit:**

Here are some more durable links to other references that are included in the prior link, just in case it ever disappears.

[How to: Create and Run a CLR SQL User-Defined Function @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k%28VS.80%29.aspx)

[Custom Attributes for CLR Routines @ TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131050.aspx)

Comment: This uses a wrapper. I don't want to use a wrapper class. I'm trying to avoid having to use the Create Assembly sql code

Comment: Ok, I see now. Creating a SQL Project and adding in code there. Brilliant, thanks a mil meklarian